# Is there any way in jmeter to pass parameter inside parameter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

''
I want to pass parameter inside parameter. 
For ex. ${var1${var2}} something like this. 
I am taking this variables from Test plan's user defined variables.
''

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:  ${__V(var1${var2})}

[Jmeter documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#what_can_do)

Comment: Please mark your question as solved then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the __V() function. It will combine the two variables.
You can refer this for more details.
https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables